# ShlowCheetah Does not Transform in VS2013 on Windows 8.1

Tags: slowcheetah

I've been using Visual Studio 2013 on a Windows 7 computer. SlowCheetah work fine in this enviroment.

However, I've recently migrated to a Windows 8.1 computer. Even with the latest update (2.5.11) of SlowCheetah in this environment, SlowCheetah is not transforming my App.Config file. I've also tried on a Windows Server 2012 computer; the issue persists.

There are no errors displayed whatsoever. Are there any log files that might have some information?

Comment: You should report this at http://connect.microsoft.com/ since Microsoft regressed the scenario. FYI I'm not investing in SlowCheetah for any updates, so hopefully you can make progress with them via connect.

Comment: Thank you. Bug submitted: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/945606

Comment: Which VS2013 Update # are the two systems at?  It would probably be good to add that to your bug report.

Comment: I had my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45022031/1584924) You need to download the version just for VS2013

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1. I had installed the package from the [SlowCheetah - XML Transforms page on the Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) and right clicked my App.config, added the transforms, modified the appropriate elements and then compiled. Nothing worked. For me this was solved by installing the Slow Cheetah Nuget package using the Library Package Manager in Visual Studio. After I added the package to my project everything worked as expected. You need to have both packages installed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to download the version  [here](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/releases/tag/v2.5.48) just for VS2013 
or look for the v2.5.48 to download.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: thanks but i am trying to build my limited reputations as a newbie.. a minus vote really hurts it here. it will be the best that just a comment of suggestion so i can update it..

Comment: If you improve your answer, I will gladly reverse the -1.