# Slowcheetah installed but there's no transform option

Tags: visual-studio-2013, app-config, slowcheetah

I have a .NET 4.5 project with MVC 5 and EF 6, in Visual Studio 2013.  I want to have transforms for app.config.

I've installed the SlowCheetah project via NuGet, and (supposedly)[https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5] now I should be able to right-click on App.config and see the option Add Transform.  But I don't.
[image: This is what I see when I right-click the app.config]

Does anyone know what are the possible reasons for this?

I've checked that the package is installed in both projects in my solution, restarted, rebuilt, etc.

Comment: I didn't know something like Slow Cheetah existed in the programming world.  It's a great RHCP song, btw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to do the following before it worked:

1. Install the package from [their site](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) instead of from NuGet
2. Restart VS

Then the Add Transform option started showing up in the drop-down menu.

Comment: I only have "Preview Transform" if I right click on Web.Debug.config, but I don't have "Add Transform" if I do it on Web.config.
I do have "Add Transform" if I right click on packages.config. Weird...

Answer (score 2):

The above answers did not work for me as it supports only VS2015. but I found the [solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah/issues/45) for my VS2013.

1. You need to download it [here](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/releases/tag/v2.5.48) and install it
2. Restart VS

Answer (score 1):

**My conditions:**

- Visual Studio Professional 2017
- SlowCheetah, v 2.5.48 installed in a C# project
- When I selected *[Right-Click]-->App.config*, there was no 
  **Add Transform** option

**My solution:**

- Downloaded and ran this:
  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WillBuikMSFT.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms
- Restarted VS 2017 and *[Right-Click]--> App.config* displayed the **Add Transform** option