# Slowcheetah installed but there's no transform option in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, slowcheetah

I have a .NET Framework 4.5.2 console project, in Visual Studio 2015. I would like to have transforms for app.config.
Very similar to [Slowcheetah installed but there's no transform option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389862/slowcheetah-installed-but-theres-no-transform-option)
But:
When I try to install SlowCheetah - XML Transforms package, as levininja sugests, I get the following error from the log:

> VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable 
>       on any currently installed products.
>          at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
>          at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

As nobody complains in the related post I assume this is a version problem on the newest Visual Studio Version.

Answer (score 1):

SlowCheetah will be taken over by Microsoft. There is already a [preview version available](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/05bb50e3-c971-4613-9379-acae2cfe6f9e).

Have you tried that version?

[More information on the preview](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2043217-support-web-config-style-transforms-on-any-file-in).

Comment: Glad to hear that :)